# Set LESS CSS Variables Outside of the LESS File

Tags: css, less

My software is used by multiple clients with their own different branding. When it comes time to update the software across clients, I have to manually change each of their installations' LESS files to use the proper styling. It's fairly simple:

```
.color_scheme("xxx");

.color_scheme (@comp) when (@comp = 'xxx') {
  @prim5: #4A91B5; @sec5: #4C8C3F;
}
```

But it's time-consuming and will only become more time-consuming as my list of clients grows. I know, via a PHP variable, what installation the user is running on. I basically want to bring `.color_scheme("xxx");` outside of the styles.less file, printed out with PHP. Something like:

```
.color_scheme("<?php echo client_name ?>");
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
```

How can I accomplish this with LESS? `@import` won't work because I need the @variable declared in-line on the HTML file, NOT within a .less, because the .less has no way of recognizing PHP.

Comment: Are you using LessPHP? If not, have a look at it. I have never used it but I think it should help you.

Comment: Looks like it is possible, but I'd like to avoid it if anyone has a solution. Possibly clever/hacky solution.